# GitHub Actions - Specify Multiple Tags with docker/build-push-action@v2

Tags: docker, github-actions

Is there a way to specify multiple tags when using `docker/build-push-action@v2`?

I tried specifying multiple tags separated by a space or comma and they both failed.

**Error**

```
buildx failed with: error: invalid tag "***/myapp:1.4.0 ***/myapp:latest": invalid reference format
```

**.github/workflows/publish.yml**

```
- name: Build and push
  id: docker_build
  uses: docker/build-push-action@v2
  with:
    context: .
    push: true
    tags: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_HUB_USERNAME }}/myapp:${{ steps.vars.outputs.tag }} ${{ secrets.DOCKER_HUB_USERNAME }}/myapp:latest
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Check here https://github.com/docker/build-push-action#customizing, add a comma between the tags, like this:

```
- name: Build and push
  id: docker_build
  uses: docker/build-push-action@v2
  with:
    context: .
    push: true
    tags: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_HUB_USERNAME }}/myapp:${{ steps.vars.outputs.tag }} , ${{ secrets.DOCKER_HUB_USERNAME }}/myapp:latest
```

Comment: Note that `build-push-action` is now at `v4`, so the action to use would be `docker/build-push-action@v4`

Answer (score 15):

You can also use a "newline-delimited string". I think this is better when you have longer strings:

```
- name: Build and push
  id: docker_build
  uses: docker/build-push-action@v2
  with:
    context: .
    push: true
    tags: |
      ${{ secrets.DOCKER_HUB_USERNAME }}/myapp:${{ steps.vars.outputs.tag }}
      ${{ secrets.DOCKER_HUB_USERNAME }}/myapp:latest
```